# Selenium with chrome gives the following error

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

MY code is:

```
service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())

options1 = Options()
options1.headless = True
driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options1)
driver1.get("https://google.com")
```

However when I try to run it I get back the following error:
`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service my path/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -9`

I tried reinstalling webdriver-manager but it didn't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) Driver Manager instead:

`pip install seleniumbase`

Then:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(browser="chrome", headless=True)
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

(Although you won't see the browser unless you set `headless` to `False`)