# Undetected Chromedriver not applying any options

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

Undetected Chromedriver is not applying my options. The windows size is not altered and the extension is not loaded. Same problem on Linux and Windows.

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_extension(proxies_extension)
options.add_argument("--window-size=500,500")

driver = uc.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

It works perfectly when I substitute the above for `options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()` and `driver = webdriver.Chrome(...`

What could I possibly be doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) with the Undetected Chromedriver context manager format to set the window size after the browser spins up:

First `pip install seleniumbase`, and then run the following script with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import DriverContext
import time

with DriverContext(uc=True, incognito=True) as driver:
    driver.get("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
    driver.set_window_size(500, 500)
    time.sleep(8)
```

And here's another format without the context manager:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver
import time

driver = Driver(uc=True, incognito=True)
driver.get("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
driver.set_window_size(500, 500)
time.sleep(8)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Do standard selenium commands work with this?

Comment: @NedHulton Yes, use the ``driver``.

Comment: (1) Can I use it like this to avoid the indentation: driver = DriverContext(uc=True)

Comment: (2) Can I add arguments in the conventional way like this: options = driver.ChromeOptions()

Comment: (3) Can I use all of the conventional selenium commands like this? driver.find_element(By.XPATH, x).click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, x).send_keys(letter)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, x).get_attribute(attr)
driver.get(url)

Comment: 1) See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74382784/7058266 - use ``driver = Driver()`` after importing ``Driver`` instead. 2) For options, see https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/618f12bee59f6dfb7070f3a1d6e285b4a4e7eb61/seleniumbase/plugins/driver_manager.py#L54 (Use ``chromium-arg="--ARG1,--ARG2"`` for args not covered.) 3) Yes.

Comment: Beautiful. Nice project BTW. Sorry, but can you explain (2) again, assuming that I am not using the command line. The following is wrong, I assume

Comment: options = driver.ChromeOptions()
#standard arguments
options.add_argument("chromium-arg=--headless=new","--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
# Base arguments
options.add_argument("--proxy=USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT")

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75699860/7058266 for the proxy. Also supports `USER:PASS@IP:PORT` format. All those ``options.add_argument`` lines are already mapped to an arg when calling ``driver = Driver()``. Automatically uses ``headless=new`` in ``uc`` mode when using ``headless=True``.

Comment: I get you, but that was really just an example. I wasn't really asking about those specifically. Just the syntax of adding arguments in general, I have about a dozen of them. I also have options.add_experimental_option( a couple of times. Thanks for clarifying this. I am sure this will takeover standard selenium eventually

Comment: So what I am doing here. options = driver.ChromeOptions() options.add_argument("chromium-arg=--headless=new","--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

Comment: Details about ``DriverContext`` vs ``Driver`` vs ``SB``, etc, are answered here: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/help_docs/syntax_formats.md Options are set here: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/seleniumbase/core/browser_launcher.py (including experimental options). There are args for most things. The blink one is already set as needed for ``uc`` mode. For ``headless=new``, use ``Driver(headless2=True)``.

Comment: If I am too lazy to look up your equivalent for each argument and I want to mix and match, it looks like this right? driver = Driver(browser="chrome", chromium-arg="--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled--window-size=500,500", uc=True, --proxy=USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `chromium-arg` values are comma-spaced. Eg: `Driver(chromium_arg='disable-blink-features="AutomationControlled",headless="new"')`. The window size must be set after the browser is launched. And `uc` mode does not support `disable-blink-features`.

Comment: driver = Driver(browser="chrome", chromium-arg='--disable-blink-features="AutomationControlled"', uc=True)
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="? It does not like the "-" symbol

Comment: It's `chromium_arg` with an underscore, not a dash. ``driver = Driver(browser="chrome", chromium_arg='disable-blink-features="AutomationControlled"')``

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for putting you through all that!

Comment: I hope that answered your original question. :)

Comment: Everything works perfectly. Thanks! Sincerely appreciated. Just one final question/comment. The worst thing about standard Selenium is trying to make changes on-the-fly. If you have a script with hundreds of lines of code and you just want to debug or edit one process without re-running your script. I currently use this thing to make edits in command line mode: idlex.sourceforge.net but its clunky and annoying. Is it possible to run Seleniumbase, login to a website, keep the browser open and then run additional commands interactively without starting script from scratch each time?

Comment: Use the built-in debugger. ``import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`` - https://seleniumbase.com/debugging-with-the-new-pdbp-debugger/ - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLnVNfMRHvs